# I am getting J2EE component error in STS 3.7.0

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting J2EE component error whenever I have opened my STS 3.7.0 tool. Why this error is coming? Is there anyone who can resolve this issue?

Comment: Full error is : An internal error occurred during: "J2EE Component Mapping Update".
java.lang.NullPointerException